# Injecting Dependencies into Entities with Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, oop

Before this is marked as duplicate I have looked around to find an answer for my question, but my scenario is a little more specific than other similar questions found on SO and I don't think anwers like "it's a bad practice" apply.

I am working on some design choices for modeling the domain following the DDD approach with Entity Framework, and I am interested in a way to inject dependencies into Entities. To be precise the only dependencies I consider worth injecting are factories for domain objects that belong to the aggregate root I am working with or wrappers around static classes like the one below:

```
public class CurrentTimeProvider : ITimeProvider
{
    public DateTime GetTime()
    {
        return DateTime.Now();
    }
}
```

The purpose of the wrapper is to make unit testing easier and I am not a fan of the double dispatch pattern for this case as it breaks encapsulation.

Sample entity:

```
public class ActivationToken
{
    protected ITimeProvider TimeProvider;

    public ActivationToken(ITimeProvider timeProvider)
    {
        TimeProvider = timeProvider;
    }

    public virtual DateTime? ConsumedTime { get; protected set; }

    public virtual void Consume()
    {
        ConsumedTime = TimeProvider.GetTime();
    }
}
```

So my question is how do I get Entity Framework to provide my dependency when creating the instance?

Comment: You haven't asked a question yet.  Perhaps if you post some entities and ask a specific question about those entities.

Comment: There *may* be examples where injecting dependencies into entities is useful and healthy. In this case I doubt it because of the phrase "to make unit testing easier". Either you introduce code that is only covered in unit tests, which is a self-fulfilling prophesy, or you make "everything else" harder, because the actual application code needs it own implementations of the unit test artifacts, making it needlessly complicated. Just to verify: would `Consume` ever be called in real-life code? And if so, how is that better than getting DateTime.Now?

Comment: Why don't you just pass it to the methods of the entity that need it?

Comment: Sorry if the example is too simplistic - in case where the token could only be consumed on specific hours I would like to be able to mock the ITimeProvider to provide specific time so my tests don't fail depending on what time they were run.

Comment: DDD and EF are very different things. I can guarantee you that you won't be doing any DDD, you are doing CRUD with DDD names. Modelling has nothing to do with coding, even less with the ORM or the db. As a thumb rule, injecting anything into a real Entity is a smell. Based on info provided I think that what you need is a couple of domain services, with `ActivationToken` being a value object. Anwyay, EF has nothing to do with that, you're asking a solution for the wrong problem.

Comment: @MikeSW thanks for your comment, but I feel like moving logic that would be included in the Consume() method (if this was not a simple illustration) to a domain service would be a step towards an aenemic model.

Comment: "a step towards an aenemic model"  you say that like it's a bad thing :)  Seriously very few people who think DDD is a good idea try to make EF entities the same as their domain classes.  Have you seen: http://thedatafarm.com/data-access/some-dddef-resources/

Comment: @MateuszMarczukiewicz I would leverage my 10 years expertise in DDD to say that using domain services in this case has nothing to do with anaemic domain. But I won't insist on it if you disagree :)

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft I think you have nailed my problem. I would like to avoid creating a separate set of EF entities to support my domain. I have managed to use nhibernate this way by using an interceptor capable of resolving dependencies and I am looking for a way to do the same with EF.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Injecting dependencies into Entity Framework entities and projects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38407102/injecting-dependencies-into-entity-framework-entities-and-projects)

Comment: The lifecycle of the two objects doesn't match, I would avoid to inject dependency as field of the domain object. If you want to write the command logic inside your entity I think the easier solution is pass the dependency in the command method. In this way the component who execute the command is in charge to pass the correct dependency. Easy to use, easy to test and avoid frameworks magic in your domain model.

Answer (score 1):

Part of the reason this is difficult is that conceptually, you are mixing up *injectibles* and *newables*.

See http://misko.hevery.com/2008/09/30/to-new-or-not-to-new/ for an explanation of the difference.

Entities in DDD fit into the 'newable' category.  Application services, domain services, repositories etc. are injectible.

An alternative approach for your example is to use 'method injection' and to pass in `ITimeProvider` directly into the `Consume` method:

```
public class ActivationToken
{

    public ActivationToken()
    {

    }

    public virtual DateTime? ConsumedTime { get; protected set; }

    public virtual void Consume(ITimeProvider timeProvider)
    {
        ConsumedTime = timeProvider.GetTime();
    }
}
```

This still allows unit testing with a mock time provider, and ensures that the entities fields are only about the state of the entity.  You can obtain an instance of the `ITimeProvider` by injecting it into the application service/use case that will call the `Consume` method.

Answer (score -2):

I think the simplest way is to avoid constructor injection and register a global Service Locator that you can access from your no-arg constructor, eg:

```
public class ActivationToken
{
    protected ITimeProvider TimeProvider;

    public ActivationToken()
    {
        TimeProvider = ServiceLocator.Instance.GetService<ITimeProvider>();
    }

    public virtual DateTime? ConsumedTime { get; protected set; }

    public virtual void Consume()
    {
        ConsumedTime = TimeProvider.GetTime();
    }
}
```

Comment: This will get him into a much bigger problem.http://blog.ploeh.dk/2010/02/03/ServiceLocatorisanAnti-Pattern/